# Правильное употребление союза "с тем чтобы"

Tags: пунктуация

Заказчикам важно объяснить, как правильно использовать материалы, как правильно собирать разъемные соединения с тем, чтобы исключить аварии и простои.

Мне кажется, что здесь правильнее бы было поставить запятую перед союзом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В примере, который вы приводите, запятую нужно поставить перед составным союзом. Т.к. согласно правилам, если придаточная часть предложения следует за главной – запятая ставится только перед союзом.

> Прим.: [Калугин] рысцой ехал на бастион, с тем чтобы по приказанию генерала передать туда некоторые приказания. Л. Толстой, Севастополь в мае.

Однако, если автор желает подчеркнуть, что на первую часть составного союза падает логическое ударение, составной союз может расчленяться.

> Ср.: Мужики тихи, робки и вежливы оттого, что у каждого для весу в кудели по камню… М. Пришвин, Мирская чаша. Я спросил у отца, что значит «особенный вечер». Отец объяснил мне, что этот вечер называется так потому, что он не похож на все остальные. К. Паустовский, Сказочник.

См.: Справочник по пунктуации. Розенталь. Д. Э.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Мне кажется. что здесь просто по смыслу расчленение не подходит.